# AJAX don't wait for response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, response

I have a webpage that has a simple AJAX request on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("ajax.php?do=something", function(response) {
        alert('response');
    });
});
```

This request takes about 15 seconds on my local test machine. The ajax.php does use session_start(), but calls session_write_close() straight after (almost straight after - it is called before any of the intensive processing is done):

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_GET['do']))
    die("!Invalid request.");

$do = $_GET['do'];

if($do=="something-else")
{
}
else if($do=="something")
{
    session_write_close();

    $customerId = $_SESSION['customerId'];

    //processing done here
}
?>
```

The problem is the once this page loads, the AJAX is fired, but then if the user clicks on a link to go to another page, the browser waits for 15 seconds and then redirects.

I want to let the user go to other pages without having to wait, or if they stay, i want them to see the response.

**EDIT** Just to clarify it a bit more. Every page has a session_start() at the top, including the one that the user is trying to go to.

I am using the session in the ajax.php, and have edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you browse away from the page while the AJAX routine is still running, won't it kill the JS cache and error out?

Comment: Use the success function of ajax calling http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: this whole scenario sounds very strange... 15 seconds is an eternity when it comes to ajax, yet it sounds like you don't need user to have the data. Have never seen an ajax request block user from getting to another page either

Comment: Have updated the original question - i need some session data in the ajax.php. I'm starting to think that the server simply isnt responding because the processing is using all the resources available at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the link that is being clicked? Where does the link point to and how does it tie in with the AJAX you have posted? From what I see the AJAX worked as expected. You are not doing anything with sessions so you might as well not have any session start or close.

I would post this as a comment but it wont let me therefore I am giving this as an answer until you can give more details.

Comment: The second page does not tie in to the AJAX at all. I simply want the user to be able to sit and wait for the ajax to complete, or click any other link on the page and leave. Currently if they click a link, it still waits for the AJAX to complete before the browser goes to the next page.

Comment: The AJAX completes very quickly and does so in the background. You have it set to do so as soon as the document is loaded which is normal. It would work fast enough to appear as if it was part of the page load. As far as the session stuff I notice you are closing the session before you are done with it. Remove the session close. If you have firebug installed you could watch the AJAX calls and get a good sense of whats happening such as status codes and response.

Comment: My understanding of session_write_close() is to tell PHP that you are done writing to the session, so that the next request can open the session instead of having to wait. After session_write_close() is called, the $_SESSION data is still available to be read.

Comment: That is true but it is not a requirement to close. It will close on its own when you are complete. If you take closing in your own hands you risk potential errors such as when another developer takes on the next script that happens to be included. In this he decided to write to session and cant figure out why it dont work. Not saying you are breaking it, but simply stating that for debugging it may be best to eliminate it for now.

Comment: I eliminated the session completely from the ajax.php and it now works fine. Not entirely sure why session_write_close wasn't working as expected, as i made a simple test and it worked properly in that. Thanks for the help anyway!